# How to send error info mail, if any error occurred in web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Here the scenario is I have  many `.aspx pages` if any page gives error, it will redirect to an error page

`Web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="customErrorPage.aspx">
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

If I get 404 error it will redirect to `Error404.aspx` works fine.

But if their any other error *(forbidden, connectionlost, service unavailable etc)* then I want to redirect to `customErrorPage.apsx`.

I want to send an email with error information (error pagename, error statusCode) when the custom error page is displayed and later after few minutes it will auto redirect user to `login.aspx`.

I have tried (not working)

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
        ex = (HttpException)Server.GetLastError();
        int errorcode = ex.GetHttpCode();
  //    Response.Redirect("Errorpage.aspx?id='" + errorcode + "'&msg='" + message + "'");
}
```

My custom error page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         getUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        // string error=  HttpContext.Current.Error.ToString();
        //   HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
       //   HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
        // meta.HttpEquiv = "refresh";
        //   meta.Content = "10;   url=Login.aspx";
        //  head.Controls.Add(meta);
}

protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //send mail function
       Email.Send("abc@asa.com", "Error Log", "custom error", true);
}
```

ALSO let me know if their is any other good way to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how i solved :

**Globasl.asax:**

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        string err = "<br><b>Error in: </b>" + Request.Url.ToString() +
            "<br><b>Error Message: </b>" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
            "<br><b>Stack Trace:</b><br>" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
       //Email sending method
       Email.Send("example@gmail.com", "Error", err, true);
    }
```

**Web.config:**

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Customerrorpage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

**Customerrorpage.aspx :** *(Auto redirect to login page in few sec)*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "4; url=Login.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for this - it is purpose built for logging unhandled exceptions (and can be signalled to also capture other exceptions).

There are a few different nuGet packages for different configurations, including emailing the exception details.

It captures lots of data and formats it in a very readable manner.

Comment: can you provide me some useful links ?